# WPF: Increased window size decreases performance

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, xaml

I'm making an application which can be dynamically populated with controls, where ItemsControl controls in XAML binds to ObservableCollection<> properties in the VM.  But when just showing a single horizontal Slider control with a custom style, I experience that the performance (frame rate) when manipulating the Slider drops when having the window full-screen compared to as small as possible.  Just increasing the window size in vertical direction causes the performance to drop.  Why is this?  And can I do anything about it?

Here's a screen shot of the window with a single Slider:

[image]

**EDIT:** The problem was related to the graphics adapter and not WPF.  The application was running on a computer with its screen connected to a DisplayLink based port replicator.  I was unaware of the low 2D performance of this graphics adapter compared to a native graphics adapter.

Comment: It seems trivially obvious that the performance drops with the size of the part that has to be repainted. It seems equally trivial to suggest a better graphics card or faster CPU to increase performance in general. Does the performance drop more than you expect? Can you add a more detailed description of the problem?

Comment: How much does it drop by? And do you see a difference in performance drop between your custom slider and the regular slider?

Comment: Did you use any Effects? like DropShadow or Blur? This may harm performance when added on large portions of UI that needs to be redrawn frequently.

Comment: @nvoigt You're absolutely right. The screen I used to test this on is connected to my port replicator, which has a DisplayLink 2D display adapter.  I didn't think of the poor performance on this.  Trying it with the screen connected to the computers hardware accelerated graphics card, the performance was much better.  Can you write it again, so I can mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance drops with the size of the part that has to be repainted. Obviously a better graphics card or faster CPU will increase performance in general.

If the performance is really bad, check your system and make sure that the screen is actually a hardware supported device (in comparison to a remote desktop, a virtual device with unspecified drivers or whatever else you can have today that is not just your monitor connected with a cable to your graphics card).